# How to set the serial, manufacturer and model details on Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have an Android application that I am testing in an emulator (SDK emulator running Nougat). I would like to get the Serial Number of the Device, Manufacturer and Model details for device management purposes.

In the emulator, I see the following values.

- Build.SERIAL = unknown
- Build.MANUFACTURER = unknown
- Build.MODEL =
  AOSP on IA x86_64 Emulator

Is there a way to change these values to something else (for testing purposes)?